# Core Data Transformer: Cannot convert value of type '[[[CLLocationCoordinate2D.Type]]]' to expected element type 'AnyClass'

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to implement a transformer class for Core Data where an entity has a transformable attribute and the custom class is [[[CLLocationCoordinate2D]]].

When implementing the the allowedTopLevelClasses computed property:

```
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        [ [[[CLLocationCoordinate2D.self]]] ]
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[[CLLocationCoordinate2D.Type]]]' to expected element type 'AnyClass' (aka 'any AnyObject.Type')
```

I tried to replace CLLocationCoordinate2D.self with [Double.self] and [Float.self]. Reading Apple docs, it seems like all classes should conform to AnyClass.

I also tried to simply return [CLLocationCoordinate2D.self] instead of my [[[CLLocationCoordinate2D.self]]] since I thought maybe the multidimensional array was causing problems.

In the raywenderlich / kodeco book Core Data by Tutorials, they use UIColor.self as an example without issue.

Comment: *"it seems like all classes should conform to AnyClass."* - classes do conform to AnyClass. But structs are not classes. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not a class, it's a struct. `UIColor` is a class.

Comment: And an Array is also not a class.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks! Looks like using a Float / Double in place wouldn't work either since those are both structs as well. I will need to use NSNumber here?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks! NSNumber or NSArray would be a solution?

Comment: An alternative is to save the coordinates as JSON (string). You can even make `CLLocationCoordinate2D` conform to `Codable`.

Comment: @vadian The data is currently being decoded from GeoJSON to be loaded into Core Data. It's a large set of coordinates and I think JSON parsing is too slow

Comment: `Encoding` creates `Data` regardless of the encoder. I guess that conversion to NSNumber and *objective-c-ish* serialization is more expensive than `Codable`

Comment: @vadian Oh okay. I think I misread what you're saying. I should use the 'Binary Data' attribute type instead of 'Transformable' and use codable for encoding and decoding to / from core data?

Comment: No, I mean a simple `String` attribute and a computed property for the conversion. Another benefit – although rather irrelevant for this case – is that a (JSON) string is searchable.

Comment: @vadian thanks! Do you know if there is a performance difference betwen using string vs data. 

For the computed property for conversion, I could just add that to my +CoreDataClass but omit the \@NSManaged attribute?

Comment: I guess there is no significant performance difference. But I prefer always the native Swift solutions although Core Data is ObjC based.